# angular 4 form field validations

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a field where I am setting its maxlength is 5. I have defined form validator saying when user types more than 5 a message is shown.
Since I have defined maxlength on the field, I cannot type more than 5 and it doesn't detect the new value entered. 
How can I detect the new key entered and show the message.

html

```
<input type="text" formControlName="zCode" class="form-control" id="zCode" name="zCode" size="5" maxlength="5">
```

Typescript:

```
fb.group({'zCode': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(5)});
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `size` and `maxlength` attributes from the markup, and see if the form validation works like what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Well if the user can't type more than 5 characters, then why display an error? That type of error message is typically reserved for situations where you have an ANGULAR max length restriction but not an HTML maxlength restriction. That way, when the user types more than 5 characters, you give them an error. In your case, it's not even possible to type more than 5 characters. Having maxlength in both places is not really efficient since one rule says "You can't type more than 5 characters", while the angular rule actually says "If you type more than 5 characters, I will have an error". Do you see how they contradict? My advice is to use one or the other. But if you want to display an error message anyway, you could always do this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" maxlength="5">
  <p *ngIf="form.controls.name.value.length === 5">You have reached your max character limit</p>
</form>
```

Comment: that makes sense. but we have a REQ something like stated

Comment: ah okay. You could also have a event emitter such as on keypress as stated by James L

Answer (score 0):

**onkeypress** still seems to work even if the maxlength value is reached.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="zCode" class="form-control" id="zCode" name="zCode" size="5" maxlength="5" onkeypress="...">
```

In the function that gets called at the onkeypress event, you could pass it the event as an object, like `onkeypress="validateMe(evt)"`, then get the evt.keyCode, which could be used to display what character was pressed last, if you wanted to do that.
You'll have to work on some logic so it's no annoying to the user, because pressing the Backspace key (so they can correct their mistake) is also going to fire the event.